# My app is no long suport ipad, when I upload my app it cause Xcode or iTunes Connect to erroneously reject my update

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My app is started up in xcode 3.2. Now I have updated the xcode to 4.5. And I don't want to suport ipad. So I set the Devices setting to iphone. Then update my app.But itunes connect reject my update with error message:

This bundle does not support one or more of the devices supported by the previous app version. Your app update must continue to support all devices previously supported. You declare supported devices in Xcode with the Targeted Device Family build setting. Refer to QA1623 for additional information:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1623/_index.html

how can i solve this problem without removing my app from apple store

Answer (score 5):

> Your app update must continue to support all devices previously supported.

Says it all really. You're not allowed to declare support for a device, then withdraw it. The only exception is when you move up the lowest supported iOS version, you can drop older devices that no longer support that version of iOS.

The document you linked to contains your three possible options.

Comment: But he's still supporting all devices previous supported -- iPads can run iPhone-only apps fine.

Comment: "Fine" isn't the term that I'd use. If I bought an iPad app, then it was updated, and suddenly it ran in crappy 2x mode with an iPhone keyboard, I'd be pretty annoyed. "Supporting" iPad in this context means you run as an iPad app.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that by some reason i had the same bundle id across different targets (iphone target and ipad target)

this lead me to try of uploading ipad app with iphone bundle id.
Easy to miss so maybe it will help one